# Is Spring Batch H2 in-memory database production stable as a Job Repository?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, h2, java-11, solrcloud

I have written a spring batch solution which currently uses the embedded H2 in-memory database.

The read and write operations uses SOLR Cloud API calls.

Ideally, we dont want to introduce an proper relational database as a job repo database, for the read-write batch operation.

I read that H2 in-memory databases are best used for Dev and Test in spring batch.

Does anyone have experience of using this H2 database in spring batch on a proper live environment dealing with millions of records in the batch processing, but batch job will ran only once a day at most?

If H2 is not stable for prod, I might have to ditch spring batch OMG, or anyother alternatives?

Open to any ideas or references.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

H2 is a `light-weight Java` database, as you mentioned yourself, that it is ideal for dev testing !

When considering production, you might be missing on lot of features which a RDBMS , NoSQL databases provide!

For e.g. Replication, memory and performance optimizations etc.

If frequent reads and writes are concerned and you don't want RDBMS, you may choose `MongoDB or Couchbase` to manipulate records , they are fast too !

So considering Millions of records, I don't think H2 would be a good choice for production databases

**A similar article might throw some light & help you decide !**

[Are there any reasons why h2 database shouldn't be used in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064030/are-there-any-reasons-why-h2-database-shouldnt-be-used-in-production)

Comment: Thanks a lot Harsh for the prompt response. I am exploring writing a bespoke batch processing app, that meets our requirement, which will be based on core features of spring batch.